# Angular2 / RxJS - updating variable after getting data from Http observable

Tags: typescript, angular

I would like to turn on my loader icon (e.g. spinner) `isLoaderEnabled` when data starts to download from API and turn it off when successfully received. What would be a proper way to turn it off?

Here is my following code.

My component:

```
this.isLoaderEnabled = true;
this.meetingService.getList();
```

My service:

```
getList() {
  this._http.get('../fake-data/someFile.json')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataStore.meetingList = data;
        this.meetingListObserver.next(this.dataStore.meetingList);
      },
      err => console.log('>>>', 'Could not load meetings list. Error: ', err),
      () => console.log('>>>', 'Done with getting meetings list.')
    );
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that your issue is trickiest than it appears at a first sight ;-) In fact, XHR doesn't support streaming so when the first callback registered within the `subscribe` method is called you already received all the data.

That said XHR supports the `onprogress` event (see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8MDO2GsCGiOJd2y2XbQk?p=preview). This allows to get hints about the progress of the download. This isn't supported out of the box by Angular2 but you

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor(private service:ProgressService) {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.onprogress = (event) => {
      service.progressEventObservable.next(event);
    };
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

The progress service could be implemented this way:

```
export class ProgressService {
  progressEventObservable:Subject<any> = new Subject();
}
```

Your service could subscribe on the progress service to be notified when the download actually starts (i.e. the first time the `next` method of `progressEventObservable` is called for the request):

```
getList() {
  var subscription = this.progressService.subscribe(event => {
    if (!this.spinner) {
      this.spinner = true;
    }
  });
  this._http.get('../fake-data/someFile.json')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .do(val => this.spinner = true)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataStore.meetingList = data;
        this.meetingListObserver.next(this.dataStore.meetingList);
      },
      err => (...),
      () => {
        this.spinner = false;
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      })
    );
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to use the spinner within the component and not the service. You could use a dedicated observable / subject, as described below:

```
spinner$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
spinner: boolean = false;

getList() {
  var subscription = this.progressService.subscribe(event => {
    if (!this.spinner) {
      this.spinner = true;
      this.spinner$.next(this.spinner); // <-------
    }
  });
  this._http.get('../fake-data/someFile.json')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .do(val => this.spinner = true)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataStore.meetingList = data;
        this.meetingListObserver.next(this.dataStore.meetingList);
      },
      err => (...),
      () => {
        this.spinner = false;
        this.spinner$.next(this.spinner); // <-------
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      })
    );
}
```

The component can subscribe on `spinner$` to be notified of changes:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeCOmponent {
  constructor(private meetingService:MeetingService) {
    this.meetingService.spinner$.subscribe((spinner) {
      this.isLoaderEnabled = spinner;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing more, I am having my spinner in my component (not the service). This changes things?

Comment: You're welcome! You need to subscribe in the component if your spinner is in it...

Comment: Could you elaborate this? I am having two files, one is component (this is where spinner gets state true or false; service is called), the other one is service - please see the initial question.

Comment: Yes, sure! I updated my answer to be close to your classes.

Comment: Thierry much appreciated, thank you again! I will dive into it.

Comment: I was thinking in general why we needed to use `progressService`, would it be enough to just turn spinner off after `meetingListObserver` passes new data to observable? (`meetingListObserver.next(this.dataStore.meetingList)`). The "download" is finished then.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is rather for the start of receiving data ;-) For the end, you're absolutely right!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108949/discussion-between-be-codified-and-thierry-templier).

Answer (score 2):

```
getList() {
  this._http.get('../fake-data/someFile.json')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .do(val => this.spinner = true)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataStore.meetingList = data;
        this.meetingListObserver.next(this.dataStore.meetingList);
      },
      err => console.log('>>>', 'Could not load meetings list. Error: ', err),
      () => this.spinner = false)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Again :) I doubt this would work as I am having component and service in separate files?

Comment: I see. Thierrys answer shows how to notify interested components using an `Observable`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make few tricks to make it work properly:

```
    //use Observable.from as lock trigger BEFORE request is sent
    var request:Observable<Response> = Observable.from([1], null).do(()=>
    {
        lock.lock();
    }).flatMap(()=>
    {
        //use finally to unlock in any case
        return this.http.post(url, body, options).finally(()=>
        {
            lock.unlock();
        });
    });
    //share sequence to avoid multiple calls when using several subscribers
    return request.share();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component `subscribe()`s to the `meetingListObserver`, just turn it off in the subscribe callback function.

If not, add another Observable or a Subject to the service and have the component subscribe to it.  When the data comes back from the service, call `next()` on the Observable or Subject.  For an example of using a Subject in a service, see  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service