# Angular 2 HTTP Progress bar

Tags: ajax, http, angular, ionic2

Is there currently a way within Angular 2 to retrieve the progress (i.e. percentage done) of an ajax call, using the angular2/http module?

I use the following code to make my HTTP calls:

```
        let body = JSON.stringify(params);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .timeout(10000, new Error('Timeout exceeded during login'))
            .toPromise()
            .then((res) => {
                ...
            }).catch((err) => {
                ...
            });
```

The goal is to write a synchronisation system. The post will return a lot of data, and I want to give the user an indication on how long the syncing will take.

Answer (score 30):

Currently (from v. 4.3.0, when using new `HttpClient` from `@ngular/common/http`) Angular provides listening to progress out of the box. You just need to create HTTPRequest object as below:

```
import { HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
...

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
  reportProgress: true,
});
```

And when you subscribe to to request you will get subscription called on every progress event:

```
http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
  // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
  // Look for upload progress events.
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
  } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
  }
});
```

More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events).

Comment: Check update Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 6):

You could leverage the `onprogress` event provided by XHR (see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8MDO2GsCGiOJd2y2XbQk?p=preview).

This allows to get hints about the progress of the download. This isn't supported out of the box by Angular2 but you can plug it by extended the `BrowserXhr` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor(private service:ProgressService) {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.onprogress = (event) => {
      service.progressEventObservable.next(event);
    };
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular2 / RxJS - updating variable after getting data from Http observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554125/angular2-rxjs-updating-variable-after-getting-data-from-http-observable/36555295#36555295)

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid implementing with XHRRequest :) but nothing to do about it ;)

Comment: In fact, it's not supported (yet) in the HTTP support of Angular2 so you need to explicitly rely on XHR...

Answer (score 4):

When you make http cals in angular2, it returns an Observable of type Response, this response is created inside class called [XHRConnection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/XHRConnection-class.html) where all the magic happens.

The XHRConnection builds the response by listening to **XMLHttpRequest's load event**, this means it will return one response at the end of the request.

**Now** to be able to alter this behavior we need to make our connection class listen to the **progress** event.

So we need to create custom Connection class, to handle the response as we see fit.

I did it this way,
*Take note that my php API returns multi response in a single request and this responses are plain strings.*

**my_backend.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Observer} from "rxjs/Observer";
import {Connection,ConnectionBackend} from "angular2/src/http/interfaces";
import {ReadyState, RequestMethod, ResponseType} from "angular2/src/http/enums";
import {ResponseOptions} from "angular2/src/http/base_response_options";
import {Request} from "angular2/src/http/static_request";
import {Response} from "angular2/src/http/static_response";
import {BrowserXhr} from "angular2/src/http/backends/browser_xhr";
import {Headers} from 'angular2/src/http/headers';
import {isPresent} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';
import {getResponseURL, isSuccess} from "angular2/src/http/http_utils"

export class MyConnection implements Connection { 
    readyState: ReadyState;
    request: Request;
    response: Observable<Response>;

    constructor(req: Request, browserXHR: BrowserXhr, baseResponseOptions?: ResponseOptions) {       
        this.request = req;
        this.response = new Observable<Response>((responseObserver: Observer<Response>) => {
            let _xhr: XMLHttpRequest = browserXHR.build();
            _xhr.open(RequestMethod[req.method].toUpperCase(), req.url);
            // save the responses in array 
            var buffer :string[] = []; 
            // load event handler
            let onLoad = () => {
                let body = isPresent(_xhr.response) ? _xhr.response : _xhr.responseText;
                //_xhr.respons 1 = "Loading data!"
                //_xhr.respons 2 = "Loading data!Ready To Receive Orders."
                // we need to fix this proble 
                // check if the current response text contains the previous then subtract
                // NOTE: I think there is better approach to solve this problem.
                buffer.push(body);
                if(buffer.length>1){
                    body = buffer[buffer.length-1].replace(buffer[buffer.length-2],'');
                }
                let headers = Headers.fromResponseHeaderString(_xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                let url = getResponseURL(_xhr);
                let status: number = _xhr.status === 1223 ? 204 : _xhr.status;
                let state:number = _xhr.readyState;
                if (status === 0) {
                    status = body ? 200 : 0;
                }
                var responseOptions = new ResponseOptions({ body, status, headers, url });
                if (isPresent(baseResponseOptions)) {
                    responseOptions = baseResponseOptions.merge(responseOptions);
                }
                let response = new Response(responseOptions);
                //check for the state if not 4 then don't complete the observer
                if(state !== 4){
                    //this will return stream of responses
                    responseObserver.next(response);
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    responseObserver.complete();
                    return;
                }
                responseObserver.error(response);
            };
            // error event handler
            let onError = (err: any) => {
                var responseOptions = new ResponseOptions({ body: err, type: ResponseType.Error });
                if (isPresent(baseResponseOptions)) {
                    responseOptions = baseResponseOptions.merge(responseOptions);
                }
                responseObserver.error(new Response(responseOptions));
            };

            if (isPresent(req.headers)) {
                req.headers.forEach((values, name) => _xhr.setRequestHeader(name, values.join(',')));
            }
            _xhr.addEventListener('progress', onLoad);
            _xhr.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
            _xhr.addEventListener('error', onError);

            _xhr.send(this.request.text());

            return () => {
                _xhr.removeEventListener('progress', onLoad);
                _xhr.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
                _xhr.removeEventListener('error', onError);
                _xhr.abort();
            };
        });
    }
}
@Injectable()
export class MyBackend implements ConnectionBackend {
  constructor(private _browserXHR: BrowserXhr, private _baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions) {}
  createConnection(request: Request):MyConnection {
    return new MyConnection(request, this._browserXHR, this._baseResponseOptions);
  }
}
```

And in the **app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS,XHRBackend} from 'angular2/http';
import {MyBackend} from './my_backend';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers:  [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        MyBackend,
        provide(XHRBackend, {useExisting:MyBackend})
    ]
    .
    .
    .
```

**Now** calling http.get will return a steam of responses.

Answer (score 2):

@Bartek Chichoki's answer is correct but it was not working for my case.
Adding observe: 'events' did the trick for me

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events'
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recomend using this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-http

otherwise messing around with xhr will make you miss sessions cookies and other stuffs

besides it'll be more portable and way easier to implement

Comment: This works great until you upgrade to Angular 5 and then the package fails because it references OpaqueToken.

Comment: i would prefer to learn the technique instead of copying someone's codes