# Angular 2 real time progress bar

Tags: angular, progress-bar

In my Angular 2 application, I have subscribed to a simple service to fetch data from a remote database and display them in a table view. Everything works fine and now I want to add a progress bar to show the real time progress for data fetching from the server.
I am currently using [primeng progressbar](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/progressbar)  component for showing the progress. But It can only be provided a fixed time to display the progress as in the code below,

```
ngOnInit() {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.value = this.value + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        if(this.value >= 100) {
            this.value = 100;
            this.msgs = [{severity: 'info', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Process Completed'}];
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

2000 means the time (in milliseconds) the progressbar is showing. 
But what I need is not this, I need to display the progress bar initially and fill the progress bar dynamically and real time until the actual data fetch completed. Progress bar should be completed and invisible only after the data fetch complete and just before data rendered to the table view.

Is there any logic to do it other than providing the static time for the progress bar? Any other solutions other than *primeng* are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

**My service class**,

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(public http:Http) {
    }

search(criteria:SearchObject):Observable<ResponseObject>{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });    
    return        this.http.post(URL,JSON.stringify(criteria),options)
      .map(res => res.json())
}
```

}

**My component class**,

```
export class SearchComponent{

    var response;
    constructor(public myService:MyService) {
    }

    search(): void {

     //Need to show the progress bar here

        var criteria = new SearchObject();
        //set data to the criteria object
       this.myService.search(criteria)
         .subscribe(
           data => {
             this.response = data;;
         },
       );            
      //close the progress bar after completing communicating with server

    }
```

}

Comment: Sounds similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158928/angular-2-http-progress-bar

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the `onprogress` event provided by XHR. This allows to get hints about the progress of the download.

This isn't supported out of the box by Angular2 but you can plug it by extended the `BrowserXhr` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor(private service:ProgressService) {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.onprogress = (event) => {
      service.progressEventObservable.next(event);
    };
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

The `ProgressService` class could look like the following:

```
export class ProgressService {
  progressEventObservable:Subject<any> = new Subject();
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8MDO2GsCGiOJd2y2XbQk?p=preview.

**Edit**

When you start to get data, you can display your progress bar and subscribe on the `progressEventObservable` observable. The latter will allow you to update the progress bar. When the request complete (in a map or subscribe callback), you can close the progress bar.

Here is a sample:

```
fetchData() {
  // Display progress bar
  // ...

  let subscription = this.progressService.progressEventObservable.subscribe(
    (event) => {
      // Update progress bar
      // ...
    }
  );

  return this.http.get('...')
    .map(res => {
      // Hide progress bar
      // ...

      // Unsubscribe
      subscription.unsubscribe();

      return res.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Your `xhr.onprogress` event in the plunkr works, but it only outputs the progress info once the download is complete. This is probably related to your edit above. Is there any chance you could adapt your edit into the plunkr? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @ThierryTemplier, I've followed your solution, I've created a CustomBrowserXhr class and ProgressService class. Also overrided the BrowserXhr provider at bootstrap method. In my search-service class, I've just logged [just as a numeric variable] the progress as your example "fetchData()" method. But in the subscription code block..the progress is not updating and in the http.get  method, I can log the progress after finishing the data fetching. Why cannot I update the progress value ? And how can I pass this progress value to my component?

Comment: It does seem @FernOfTheAndes is right: this is all and well, yet the actual progress will be repercuted all at once when the (upload in my case) if completely finished, which kind of defeats the purpose. Is there anything we should pay special attention to for the events to bubble in the actual view?