# how to track progress in angular 2 service call

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I'm told that we use services to talk to the database or other data repository.  while the query is in execution, I'd like to be able to put up a progress bar on the UI.

How do you track percent complete?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [refer this to do it sanely with angular2 HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158928/angular-2-http-progress-bar) module.

Otherwise the same can be done with XHR `progress` event in jQuery:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
export class ProgressLoader {
  percentage$: Subject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.percentage$ = new Subject();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://google.com',
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest(),

        xhr.addEventListener("progress", (evt) => {
         this.percentage$.next(parseInt(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100, false) + '%');
        }, false);
        return xhr;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: ok.  so my question here is then you would have to use an observable to manage the percentage in the Component?

Comment: @arcee123 You can use EventEmitter to emit new percentage value and subscribe to it in components to be used in the view (updated code above).