# angular2 file upload with json data

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upload files in my angular2 application. Currently I'm using the ng2-file-upload directives and it works for uploading files. However, I would like to also upload a JSON object.Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by  upload a JSON object ? Send it by an http request ?

Comment: shopcontact(request) {debugger;
    var front_print=this.requestv;
    var back_print=this.requestv;
   let front_printvalue: File = this.requestv[0];
   let back_printvalue: File = this.requestv[0];
   var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("front_print",front_printvalue,front_printvalue.name);
    formData.append('back_print',back_printvalue,back_printvalue.name); 
    
    return this._http.post(this._url + 'shop', request,
      {
        headers: headers,

Comment: i want to file upload along with json data

Comment: var tshirtbody = "event_name=" + request.eventname + "&name=" + "vasu"+ "&front_print=" + fdg+ "vasu"  +  "&item_quality=" + 2 + "&email=" + request.email + "&mobile=" + request.mobile + "&no_of_items=" + request.nooftshirts + "&item_type=" + request.tshirttype + "&text_print=" + request.text_print;
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("front_print",front_printvalue,front_printvalue.name);
    formData.append('back_print',back_printvalue,back_printvalue.name); 
return this._http.post(this._url + 'shop', body,formData )

Comment: I finally found a proper way to upload a file and send some JSON within the same request and made a proper answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693966/how-to-angular2-post-json-data-and-files-in-same-request/47408232#47408232