# Angular 2+ send request with Json data + FormData

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload

Is there a way to send FormData and a json object at the same time in http.request of angular 2+? I need the solution for angular2+, not to angularjs.

```
let data = {id: 1, name: 'test'};
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileData', file); //file from inputfile

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

let options =  new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
options.method = 'POST';
options.body = data; //data is my object

//options.formData= formData; //formData is my FormData with file data to upload

this.http.request(url, options);
```

Comment: I finally found a proper way to upload a file and send some JSON within the same request and made a proper answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693966/how-to-angular2-post-json-data-and-files-in-same-request/47408232#47408232

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the file and the JSON object on the "formData" object like this example:

```
public submitForm(picture: File, data: any): Observable<any> {
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('picture', picture);
 formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```